# Sugar daddy scam or no?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

So I have someone who is interested in a sugar daddy/sugar baby arrangement but in order to receive the money he wants my mobile banking username and password. Is it a scam ?

Comment: Ask yourself: Self, If I wanted to *send* money to someone, do I need their mobile banking username & password, or would I use one of the 'normal' money transfer services like everyone else does who doesn't try to scam people?

Comment: the real question is who are these sugar babies that ask these kind of questions. the world is out of balance /s

Comment: @CQM: Yes, it seems the world has gotten quite strange in places.  If I were to become someone's "sugar daddy", I would certainly expect regular sex as part of the deal.  That is traditionally the definition of the term.

Comment: @jamesqf At this point, we should add that prostitutes are traditionally paid in cash.

Comment: @jamesqf Never heard of phone sex or camming?